# Канализация может быть центральной?

Tags: выбор-слов

Канализация может быть центральной? Или централизованная все же?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Канализация бывает местной (частной, автономной) и централизованной (системной, построенной по единому замыслу).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]